# Code inside conditional is_tax() only working when term has posts

Tags: custom-taxonomy

Using Genesis framework, but I don't think Genesis-specific.

I have a series of conditionals for various post types and archives to filter the H1 title. It's working perfectly for is_singular() and is_post_type_archive() conditionals.

The code below (using the Code Snippets plugin) is working when the query returns posts.

However, it's NOT working when no posts are returned. It's behaving as if is_tax() is returning false.

```
add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'bn_post_title_output', 1 );
function bn_post_title_output( $title ) {
if ( is_tax() ) {
$title = sprintf( '<h1>%s</h1>', apply_filters( 'genesis_post_title_text', single_term_title( '', false ) ) );
return $title;
}
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You gave us just a bit of information. Please, post more lines of your code so we can see where you are using `is_tax()`, is it within a hook, are you calling other conditional functions before `is_tax()`? The thing is, it's probably returning false because of where and/or when you are calling it.

Comment: An archive is a collection of posts, an archive with no posts isn’t an archive, it’s a 404.

Comment: @filipecsweb I've edited the code to show more context.

Comment: @Milo I had my suspicions, but the archive has a template and still displays a title and description. Just can't work out how to filter the title.

Comment: @Milo it doesn't work like that, it definitely depends on how the theme was coded.

Comment: @Andy I was expecting more lines, but you might want to change your priority from 1 to at least 10. `add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'bn_post_title_output', 1 );` to `add_filter( 'genesis_post_title_output', 'bn_post_title_output', 15 );`, for instance. The higher the number more your code have the priority of changes. You might also want to debug `is_tax()` and/or `get_queried_object()` using `var_dump()`.

Comment: @filpecsweb it's Genesis Sample theme if that helps - https://www.studiopress.com/sample/

Comment: @filipecsweb not sure what else to add... I'm using Code Snippets plugin, but tried it in functions.php too.

Comment: Did you try changing the priority from 1 to 15?

Comment: @filipecsweb yes, but no difference

Comment: What about debugging `is_tax()` and `get_queried_object()` using `var_dump()`? Please, debug it and post your results.

Comment: get_queried_object() isn't returning anything for the empty archive, but an archive with posts returns this (and more):

`object(WP_Term)#9205 (11) { ["term_id"]=> int(19) ["name"]=> string(7) "Housing" ["slug"]=> string(7) "housing" ["term_group"]=> int(0) ["term_taxonomy_id"]=> int(19)`

Comment: `is_tax()` returns `bool(true)` on archive with posts. Again, nothing on archive without posts.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly not the most elegant. This is my new code snippet based on the Genesis archive.php

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_content_sidebar_wrap', 'custom_do_archive_headings_headline', 12, 3 );

function custom_do_archive_headings_headline( $heading = '', $intro_text = '', $context = '' ) {
if (is_tax()) {
$archive_title = single_term_title( '', false );
printf( '<div class="title-banner"><div class="inner-wrap"><h1 class="entry-title">%s</h1></div></div>', strip_tags( $archive_title ) );
    }
}
```

Thanks @filipecsweb @Milo